# Deleting all folders older than a specified date, except some

Tags: bash, date, directory, except

I have to delete all directories in a path, which are older than a specified date except some of them, in bash.

I know the names of the directories which shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/226660/deleting-all-folders-older-than-a-specified-date-except-some-of-them).

Answer (score 2):

Use `find`. Here's an example which should work at least on FreeBSD:

```
find . -type d -not -newerct 'x days ago' -not -name dir1 -not -name dir2 -delete
```

Comment: I think it's `-not -mtime n` for **older**

Comment: so if i had to script it... it's like

#!/bin/nsh

find /path/test-source/* -type d -not -newerct '30 days ago' -not -name "events" -not -name "logs" -delete 

exit 0

i'm sorry but i'm a beginner...

Comment: @Mikjcl You should read some introduction to bash scripting, e.g.
http://linuxreviews.org/beginner/Bash-Scripting-Introduction-HOWTO/en/x67.html

Comment: @Antoine: You could do the above as `-not -ctime -x` where x is an integer number of days. The disadvantage is that specifying a time period is difficult this way, whereas with -newerXt it is pretty easy. The user did specify "A specified date" so -newerXt is appropriate. Whether ctime is more correct than mtime is debatable. Should directory renames and permission changes be counted as changes?

Comment: ok i reach this.. so now i can move some directories older than 30 days to another path... but how can i filter the directories which should not move?

#!/bin/nsh

find /path/test-source/* -mtime +30 -exec mv {} /path/test-mv-to/ \;

Comment: @Antoine: It's -mtime +n for older. Also, `-newerct` is not "creation time" it's "change time" as in "when was the inode changed?" Probably not useful for this purpose. Also, the OP said "specified date" so I'd use `-newermt 2010/12/23`. @Mikjcl: See the `-not -name dir1`? That's how.